# Xcode add multiple frameworks to multiple targets and projects

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1, ios-frameworks

I have dozens of projects that I need to update, and they have two seperate Targets each. I need to add 9 new Frameworks to each of the Targets in each project.

I know I can use CMD+CLICK to select all 9 frameworks at one time and add them to each Target. However is there any way I can add them to both targets at once?

What about adding all these frameworks to multiple projects at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there does not appear to be anyway to add frameworks to multiple targets or projects at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this (or kinda of a quicker way than the original way).

- First add the framework(s) to the first target.
- Go to the Navigator area(left pane of xcode), and select the frameworks folder to see the list of Frameworks.
- Click through each framework, and note that on the right pane of Xcode, in File Inspector, it is applied only to the first target, but you see that the other targets are unchecked.
  -Check all the additonal targets you want to have the frame work and its now added to that target.
  -Repeat steps for all the frameworks you want shared across multiple targets.